# How can I use an older version of package gregor?

Tags: racket

Here's how to simulate it.

```
$ cat t1.rkt
#lang racket/base
(require gregor)
(display "hello")
```

I'm running Racket 6.12.  But the same happens to Racket 7.2.

```
$ racket t1.rkt
explode-path: contract violation
  expected: (or/c path-for-some-system? path-string?)
  given: #f
  context...:
   /usr/share/racket/collects/racket/path.rkt:116:0: do-explode-path
   /usr/share/racket/collects/racket/path.rkt:126:0: find-relative-path7
   /home/me/.racket/6.12/pkgs/tzinfo/tzinfo/private/zoneinfo.rkt:118:2: for-loop
   /home/me/.racket/6.12/pkgs/tzinfo/tzinfo/private/zoneinfo.rkt:108:0: read-tzids
   /home/me/.racket/6.12/pkgs/tzinfo/tzinfo/private/zoneinfo.rkt:71:0: make-zoneinfo-source
   /usr/share/racket/collects/racket/contract/private/arrow-val-first.rkt:388:18
   /home/me/.racket/6.12/pkgs/tzinfo/tzinfo/main.rkt:63:0: system-tzid
   /usr/share/racket/collects/racket/contract/private/arrow-val-first.rkt:388:18
   /home/me/.racket/6.12/pkgs/gregor-lib/gregor/private/moment.rkt: [running body]
   /home/me/.racket/6.12/pkgs/gregor-lib/gregor/private/generics.rkt: [traversing imports]
   /home/me/.racket/6.12/pkgs/gregor-lib/gregor/private/clock.rkt: [traversing imports]
   /home/me/.racket/6.12/pkgs/gregor-lib/gregor/main.rkt: [traversing imports]
   /home/me/issue-gregor/t1.rkt: [traversing imports]

$ racket --version
Welcome to Racket v6.12.
```

How could I go back to an older version of gregor?  I installed it this one with `raco pkg install gregor` and installed all its dependencies.

Comment: Thing one: I can't reproduce this, it runs fine on my installation. I'm running an up-to-date version of gregor (589f6ffbb67e044cb50), and a local build of racket (Welcome to Racket v7.2.0.5.).

Comment: Ooh sorry, thing two

Comment: Right, as I was saying: have you considered filing a bug report for gregor directly? The URL for this is https://github.com/97jaz/gregor/issues  .

Comment: Finally, you'll probably get a faster response for questions like this on the racket-users mailing list  (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/racket-users). I happen to know that the author of Gregor is quite active on that mailing list.

Comment: Oh! Also, you definitely can go back to an earlier version of gregor, but that's not the path I would suggest (e.g. raco pkg update --clone and then go in and roll the repo back manually, then rebuild.... let me know if you want more detailed instructions).

Comment: The problem was that I did not have the `tzdata` package installed in the GNU Ubuntu system.  So gregor is [missing those files](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/all/tzdata/filelist) and crashing ungracefully.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of Gregor. (I don't normally post on Stack Overflow, or even use it much, but John Clements brought this to my attention.)

There's a bit of an unfortunate naming issue here, since `tzdata` appears to be the name of an Ubuntu package that provides the normal zoneinfo files, as well as being the name of a [Racket package](https://pkgs.racket-lang.org/package/tzdata) that also provides those files.

`gregor` depends on a package called `tzinfo`. `tzinfo`, in turn, *conditionally* depends on `tzdata` (the Racket one, not the Ubuntu one). Specifically, it only depends on `tzdata` on Windows systems. This is because I assumed that all Unix systems would have the zoneinfo files. (It never occurred to be that anyone would run a Unix without them these days.) But it is certainly the case that `tzinfo` (and thus `gregor`) will not work unless it can find zoneinfo files.

Maybe I should update the documentation with a conspicuous warning. I'd rather not make `tzinfo` *unconditionally* depend on `tzdata` (again, the Racket one), because most Unix systems will already have the necessary files, and it could be unduly confusing for `gregor` to use a version of them different from the one the system is using.